# Reload window even if that browser tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web-applications

is there any way in any programming language to reload the webpage even if that particular browser tab is not active. In simple term i want to reload the web page by doing some other work on different tabs.

Comment: Who marked this question as duplicate? The duplicate mentioned above is not even related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check inactivity of user using java script then refresh the same page  like

```
<head>
```

Comment: <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>